# How to make an eclipse plugin for text comparison of two files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I plan to make a text comparison plugin for eclipse which basically provides a visual aid for changes that are required in the file and allows the user to accept or reject them. It is very much in lines of subclipse for svn or any other code comparison tools. I already found a good source to perform the text comparison but I'm looking for some pointers regarding the implementation of the UI in eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse already supports this. Select two files, go to Compare With, choose 'Each other'. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Buy a copy of "Eclipse Plugins" by Clayberg and Rubel.

For what it is worth ... Eclipse already includes text file comparison tools as standard.